# Provisioning prometheus with saltstack

Tags: salt-stack, prometheus

Using this formula:

https://github.com/bechtoldt/saltstack-prometheus-formula.git

for provisioning prometheus, I can't achieve convergence.

Fails pretty early on:

```
# salt prometheus-master state.apply test=True
prometheus-master:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'prometheus' in env 'base'
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

Have 'prometheus' defined in bot states & pillars top.sls.

Comment: Could you please also post a selection from your top.sls file where this Minion seems to get matched with the prometheus sls files? And how did you use the prometheus sls files? I don't see an init.sls or prometheus.sls file in this repository so you should have changed those filenames if you wanted to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

bechtoldt's formula requires additional code taken from his GitHub repository to work, formhelper, https://github.com/bechtoldt/salt-modules/blob/master/_modules/formhelper.py in https://github.com/bechtoldt/salt-modules which is his special way to manage pillars that gives him more flexibility to manage versions.

It is certainly not as straightforward as pillars are on their own, and you will need to understand that to operate the prometheus formula, so unfortunately it is not going to work out of the box.